# Double Navigation Bar in View

Tags: ios, iphone, navigation, constraints

I have a problem with a "double" navigation bar in a screen of my iPhone app.

Starting position:

Xcode 8, Swift

I have a TableView with static lines that is embedded in a navigation controller. From the first cell I then call a screen (Segue Show Detail), which is very complex (labels, text boxes, buttons, etc.). When  I execute the "Reset to suggested constraints" function on the screen, the screen is supplied with "generated" constraints. This is still clear. When I run my app in the simulator (iPhone 6) or my own iPhone 6, I see on the above screen a status bar, then my right navigation bar (Back button, title) and below an "empty" 2.Navigation bar. This decreases the screen down and is no longer fully visible. If I delete the constraints for the screen with the "Clear Constraints" function, the screen in the simulator (i6) looks good as I develop in the storyboard for the iPhone 7. But when I connect my own iPhone 6 and test, the screen does not fit completely to my iPhone, because right and down is something truncated.

I suspect the error in the "generated" constraints.

Now my question:

How can I check the generated Contraints (well over 100) for errors?

In the Internet and the forum I found nothing, which could help me.

Workaround for me:

The top UI element on the screen is a label across the entire width of the screen. For this label, I set a constraint manually, in addition to the generated constraints

```
 Label.top = Top Layout Guide.bottom + 44,
```

whose value I then change to the value

```
 Label.top = Top Layout Guide.bottom
```

This causes the label to slide directly below the status bar in the storyboard. The navigation bar is then no longer visible in the storyboard. This makes the placement of UI-Elements at the bottom of the screen somewhat more difficult because you do not know exactly which space is still available.

The display in the simulator (i6) and on my iPhone 6 looks however through the workaround ok.

For your help I would be very grateful.

Greeting Reinhard

Comment: Try to check/uncheck "Extended edges: Under Top Bars" in ViewController's Attribute Inspector inside the storyboard.

Comment: I have already tried. Did not help. I think this is a constraint problem ...